# Passing app object in requirejs + marionette application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

Working with Marionette/Backbone and having trouble passing the App object in order to trigger a custom event.

Specifically, requirejs is throwing the following: "Error: Module name "app" has not been loaded yet for context: _".

**Edit:** The offending code is "var App = require('app');" within appController.js.

From what I've read, that message refers to a circular reference or the script not being loaded yet. How should I structure my code to avoid this?

*Note 1:* At the moment, I'm not using r.js. I do have a grunt build process, but haven't had a chance to set up r.js. Only mentioning it in case that would alleviate my issue.

*Note 2:* I'm not using Marionette's stock module because I wanted to learn requirejs.

Thanks in advance.

```
//config.js
require.config({
   paths: {
       jquery: '../jquery',
       bootstrap: '../bootstrap',
       underscore: '../lodash',
       backbone: '../backbone',
       'backbone.babysitter': '../backbone.babysitter',
       'backbone.wreqr': '../backbone.wreqr',
       marionette: '../backbone.marionette',
       text: '../text'
   },
   enforceDefine: true,
   shim: {
       'bootstrap': {
           deps: ['jquery'],
           exports: '$'
       },
   }
});
define(
    ['app', 'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'marionette', 'bootstrap'],
    function(App, $, _, Backbone, Marionette) {
        App.start();
    }
);

//app.js
define(function(require) {
    var Marionette = require('marionette'),
        // and AppRouter, AppController
    var app = new Marionette.Application();
    app.addInitializer(function() {
        var router = new AppRouter({
            controller: AppController
        });
    });
    app.on('start', function() {
        Backbone.history.start();
    });
    app.vent.on('custom:event', function(a) {
        console.log('caught custom:event, received: ' + a);
    });
    return app;
});

// appRouter.js
define(function(require) {
    var Marionette = require('marionette');
    return Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        appRouter: {
            '': 'main'
        }
    });
});

//appController.js
define(function(require) {
    return {
        main: function() {
            var App = require('app');
            App.vent.trigger('custom:event', ['test']);
        }
    }
});
```

---

**Update:**

Of course after posting this question, I find a possible solution. If I adjust appController.js to the following, it works without issue. Still, the solution doesn't feel right. Would I have to duplicate it for every route?

```
//appController.js (version 2)
define(function(require) {
    return {
        main: function() {
            require(['app'], function(app) {
                app.vent.trigger('custom:event', ['test']);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

---

**Update 2**

If anyone is curious, this is how I got it working with Backbone.Wreqr (thank you @arisalexis). Only showing files changed from code above.

```
//app.js
define(function(require) {
    var Marionette = require('marionette'),
        Wreqr = require('backbone.wreqr'),
        // and AppRouter, AppController
    var app = new Marionette.Application();  
    app.addInitializer(function() {
        var router = new AppRouter({
            controller: AppController
        });
    });
    app.on('start', function() {
        Backbone.history.start();
    });
    // Get hook to global channel and listen for events!
    var channel = Wreqr.radio.channel('global');
    channel.vent.on('custom:event', function(a) {
        console.log('caught custom:event, received: ' + a);
    });
    return app;
});

//appController.js
define(function(require) {
    var Wreqr = require('backbone.wreqr');
    var channel = Wreqr.radio.channel('global');
    return {
        main: function() {
            channel.vent.trigger('custom:event', 'test');
        }
    }
});
```

Note, in general, the router's controller should not have any logic in it. The code presented in this question is a proof of concept.

Comment: Could you post `paths` of requirejs's config? I guess you haven't declared `app` there.

Comment: Added actual contents of paths and shim (note, I found I didn't need shims for backbone or marionette). As you said, I do not have app in the "paths". I thought requirejs knows to look for it in the baseUrl? In fact, it is being loaded. If I comment out "var App = require('app');" in appController.js, the application loads as expected.

Comment: You need to add `app`'s path to the `paths`. And then you can use the 1st version. The fact that after commenting the `var App = require('app');` didn't break you code, means that it was loaded elsewhere and declared globally.

Comment: Added `app`'s path to `paths`, but unfortunately, still getting the same message. Note, checked Firebug, and app.js is being loaded (e.g. not 404'ing, 500'ing, etc).

Comment: Could you add `debugger` in a few places to check load order of  files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and could not solve it, luckily because it will be deprecated in version 3.

From the docs:

To access this application channel from other objects within your app you are encouraged to get a handle of the systems through the Wreqr API instead of the Application instance itself.

```
var globalCh = Backbone.Wreqr.radio.channel('global');
globalCh.vent;
```

use this or take a look at https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.radio

Comment: Thank you @arisalexis. That's the hint I needed.